# Pseudo element exists but not visible

Tags: css

The pattern has before content inject into the page, but it's not visible can you please suggest what is the issue?

```css
.aloha {
  font-family: Medium;
  font-size: 74px;
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 85px;

  
}

.aloha:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  color: red;
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <h1 date-text='TEXT' class='aloha'>TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: Since this is a simple typo I recommend to delete this question as it has no value to future users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your HTML. Replace `date-text` with `data-text` on your `<h1>` element:

```css
.aloha {
  font-family: Medium;
  font-size: 74px;
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 85px;
}
.aloha:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  color: red;
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text='TEXT' class='aloha'>TEXT</h1>
```

Comment: Flag to close as off-topic due to a typo

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, will pay more attention next time :)

Comment: @j08691 - just for info: is in such a case an answer ok or should I only flag and comment? (I flagged)

Comment: You should always flag typo questions for closure. Answering is optional, but can easily be done as a comment.